# MS Project Server 2010 Java API

Tags: java, ms-project

I'm looking for a way to write a Java application interacting with an MS Project Server 2010. I've read that a web API exists for MS Project Server, but could find no documentation on it. All the examples I've found so far use some C# library hiding all the API calls.

I'll be thankful for your advice on what tech to use to make this interaction possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Java API for Project Server.

Project Server API is based on SOAP web services, but it uses non-standard data structure .NET DataSets to exchange data with clients. And actually the only problem - there is no implementation of the DataSets for Java.

The most common solution is to write a proxy web service using .NET which converts the DataSets to something supported by Java and write a Java client which works with the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't it possible to write a custom serializer in Java? Where can I find documentation on MS Project Server SOAP API?

Comment: Everything is possible, but nobody wants to do that. Here is some documentation: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457477(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Okay, looks like I'll have to stick to C#. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use C# the syntax is simular to java